Pull down and an external pull up resistor on the same GPIO pin of a Li-ion battery charger
I've got a battery charging chip that says it has a pull down resistor internally on its Charge Enable (CE) pin to automatically enable charging of a battery if a battery is present and power is available. What if I don't want to enable charging first, can I put a stronger pull up resistor on this same pin to VCC to disable charging and have a GPIO from the control board to program whether I want it to charge by calling
digitalWrite(pin, LOW)

to enable?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Presumably this chip's $V_{DD}$ is the same as your microcontroller, +5V. Is that correct?

Yes you can, the enable pin (CE) just needs to be over 1.5V to be HIGH. I would properly use a transistor to pull the CE pin low when I need too enable it. If you need to use a strong pull-up, the GPIO could maybe be damaged also if it is connected to a higher voltage than the MCU supply.

The transistor is a good idea. The charger chip will not allow the CE pin voltage to exceed input supply, so the MCU cannot push the pin high. Also the other way around, the external pull-up to disable must pull to charger VDD, and if for example the MCU runs at lower voltage or is unpowered, it will not work with pull-up higher to MCU supply voltage. Some 3.3V MCUs have 5V tolerant pins when inputs, but not when outputs. And they don't tolerate 5V if they are unpowered.

I looked closer at the datasheet of the chip I am trying to mod up and it says the CE pin max current is 8uA with the typical being 5uA. So if I use a pull up resistor then it would need to be about 660Kohm at 3.3V. This worked and disabled the CE pin until I had the software pull it down. I like the idea of the transistor, unfortunately this is modding a small PCB which I would prefer not to add too much bulk. On my next PCB design, I will need to look into designing the transistor.
